# gcc error when declaring reference to reference type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gcc4.8, cray

In the OpenCV library there is a

```
typedef const _InputArray& InputArray;
```

In our code we have the following function definition:

```
void wimshow(const String& winName, InputArray &img) {
```

When compiling this the following error occurs:

`error: cannot declare reference to 'cv::InputArray {aka const class cv::_InputArray&}'
 void wimshow(const String& winName, InputArray &img) {`

The weird thing is that this error only occurs using GCC 4.8.1 in the Cray environment.  Compiling in a normal Linux environment with GCC 4.8.1 works without errors.
At first glance I would say that a reference to a reference type is not very meaningful anyway but I am curious about what could cause the different compiler behavior!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This appears to be a C++03/C++11 difference.**

In C++11, the extra `&` (and the `const`, incidentally) are supposed to be ignored:

> `[C++11: 8.3.2/6]:` **If a typedef (7.1.3)**, a type template-parameter (14.3.1), or a decltype-specifier (7.1.6.2) **denotes a type `TR` that is a reference to a type `T`, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type “lvalue reference to `T`”**, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to *cv* `TR`” creates the type `TR`.
>
> *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> int i;
> typedef int& LRI;
> typedef int&& RRI;
> LRI& r1 = i;           // r1 has the type int&
> const LRI& r2 = i;     // r2 has the type int&
> const LRI&& r3 = i;    // r3 has the type int&
> RRI& r4 = i;           // r4 has the type int&
> RRI&& r5 = 5;          // r5 has the type int&&
> decltype(r2)& r6 = i;  // r6 has the type int&
> decltype(r2)&& r7 = i; // r7 has the type int&
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

The pertinent example here is `r1`; although `typedef int& LRI` isn't precisely like your `typedef`, the example is equivalent due to the following passage having already dropped your `const`:

> `[C++11: 8.3.2/1]:` *[..]* Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored. *[..]*

However, the `[C++11: 8.3.2/6]` wording does not exist in C++03! In fact, we can compare behaviours between the two languages with the following example program:

```
struct T1 {};

typedef T1& T2;

int main()
{
    T1 x;
    T2& t = x;
}
```

- [Output in C++03](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e1bff21309be824): `error: cannot declare reference to 'T2 {aka struct T1&}'`
- [Output in C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/066c5f612cce93fb): nothing!

<sup>(ignoring warnings about unused variables)</sup>

So, check your compilation flags on each platform to ensure that you're using the same language on both. It may be that the default on the Cray is C++03, but the default on your platform is C++11. Use the `-std=c++03`/`-std=c++11` flag to state which to use explicitly.

Comment: Blazing fast help. I could watch your answer change and improve. Good work!

Comment: Exatcly as you said, `-std=c++11` does not yield this error. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Callahan: Groovy. :)

Answer (score 1):

References to references (as `const const`) are supposed to be ignored to make meta-template programming easier,  So the error you're seeing on the Cray system is a bug.

Comment: That is the reason I did not consider this an error. When using a library the actual typedef should not be my concern and hence an extra `&` can actually be ignored.